# No verification for DSA key ID 46181433FBB75451

Tags: apt, ssh, lubuntu, gnupg, usb-installation

Hello Ubuntu comunity!

Greetings from Czech republic, Europe. Sorry for my very simple english, as I'm not good in it and I even do mix it with german and czech. Also sorry for local language from Terminal outputs. If some one please could help me out, I would be really very glad.

To the issue:
I try to make a Lubuntu 18.04 installation USB stick for i686 notebook. But I do not get a OK for ISO file and in the step earlier the verification for the first key 46181433FBB75451.

What I did so far? Red the Instructions in [Tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview), then:

Tutorial step 3)

Downloaded all 3 files into standard Download directory, which name in czech is "Stažené"

1. lubuntu-18.04-alternate-i386.iso
2. SHA256SUMS.gpg
3. SHA256SUMS (Note: this was a little bit difficult, as I was not able to get it with simple clicking on it. It opened in the Webbrowser window after clicing on it. I had to save the website to the same directory as these 2 files before.)

Tutorial step 4 a)

Getting keys run well. Here is the result after once more typed the command:

```
:~/Stažené$ gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x46181433FBB75451 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: požaduji klíč 46181433FBB75451 ze hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: požaduji klíč D94AA3F0EFE21092 ze hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: klíč 46181433FBB75451: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" beze změn
gpg: klíč D94AA3F0EFE21092: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" beze změn
gpg: Celkový počet zpracovaných klíčů: 2
gpg:              beze změn: 2
```

Info: "beze změn" means "no changes"

Tutorial step 4 b)

Fingerprints are also OK:

```
:~/Stažené$ gpg --keyid-format long --list-keys --with-fingerprint 0x46181433FBB75451 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
pub   4096R/D94AA3F0EFE21092 2012-05-11
      Fingerprint klíče = 8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid                          Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   1024D/46181433FBB75451 2004-12-30
      Fingerprint klíče = C598 6B4F 1257 FFA8 6632  CBA7 4618 1433 FBB7 5451
uid                          Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>
```

Tutorial step 5)

Now comes the trouble. I do not get the verification for the first key 46181433FBB75451. Only the second one is mentioned.

```
:~/Stažené$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: Podpis vytvořen Út 27. říjen 2020, 21:00:26 CET
gpg:                použití RSA klíče D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: Dobrý podpis od "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>"
gpg: VAROVÁNÍ: Tento klíč není certifikován důvěryhodným podpisem!
gpg:          Nic nenaznačuje tomu, že tento podpis patří vlastníkovi klíče.
Primární fingerprint klíče: 8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
```

Tutorial step 6)

When I try to check ISO file, I get no answer. Empty row comes after a while, when I  enter command.

```
:~/Stažené$ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK
:~/Stažené$
```

Does, please, anyone know, what I do not right and what I have to do? Thank you in advance for any hint.

On websites, using also google.com search, I found a lot good Hints and Solutions for particular steps, but not one for case I try to solve. Probably I do not know how shuld I expres the topic I'm looking for.

Karel

---

By the way, on this occasion I would like to express, that I'm very sorry that the software for i386 is no more supported. I have several "old" computers with i386 architecture and they are sitll capable to run. In my opinion is it still better to run them, if they can, then to recycle them. Even if I have to cannibalise them for spare parts. And to be true, as I'm older is it for me more and more difficult to learn new ways how to install for me unfamiliar operation software (smiley).

Comment: Please run `export LC_ALL=C` and then run these commands again. You'll get output in English.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: I'll provide the Lubuntu manual which reveals another text on how to perform the checks (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.1/retrieving_the_image.html)   The manual I gave is for the *stable* or 21.04 release; you can change the word *stable* in the URL to say *lts* and it'll show you the page for the current LTS (ie. 20.04) but none will match 18.04 as it's EOL as far as Lubuntu are concerned (*flavors* have 3 years of supported life only)   FYI:  I tested *i386* for Lubuntu releases up to 19.04 or the last; but Debian 11/Bullseye also runs on those old *i386* boxes (i686 actually)